# How to create Google account in emulator?

Tags: android, emulation

I want to create a google account in emulator. When I create an emulator, there is no Google APIs in my target,

[image]

What should I do to create a google account.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install Google APIs from the Android SDK manager. In Eclipse, you can get to it by going to `Window -> Android SDK Manager`. Once there, check Google APIs for the API level you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download from Sdk manager, Red marks mean needed to download necessaries files.

[image]

Set an emulator like this.

[image]

Comment: What message are you getting?